# Rational normal curve of degree 4

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadrics

Consider the rational normal curve of degree 4. It can be realized as the intersection of a certain number of quadrics. Usually in examples we consider those quadrics to be singular. However, can at least two of those quadrics be non-singular?

**Edit:** I mainly wish to know if it is possible for the rational normal curve of degree 4 to lie on the intersection of two non-singular quadrics.

Comment: Are you just asking if the rational normal curve lies on two non-singular quadrics, or do you need their intersection of those two to have some other properties?

Answer (score 1):

The rational normal curve

\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{P}^1 & \to & \mathbb{P}^4 \\
[s:t] & \mapsto & [s^4 : s^3 t : s^2 t^2 : s t^3 : t^4 ]
\end{array}

is cut out of $\mathbb{P}^4$ by the quadrics

$$x_0 x_2 - x_1^2 = x_1 x_3 - x_2^2 = x_2 x_4 - x_3^2 = x_0 x_4 - x_1 x_3 = 0$$

A quadric hypersurface is singular iff the corresponding quadric form is not of full rank.

So write

$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\qquad B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
$$C = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \qquad D = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and pick some linear combinations making the determinants non-vanishing, e.g. $A + B - D$.

Proceeding in this way, you can see e.g. that the rational normal curve of degree 4 is the intersection of the four smooth quadrics

$$-x_1^2 + x_0 x_2 - x_2^2 - x_1 x_3 + 2 x_0 x_4 = 0,$$
$$-x_1^2 + x_0 x_2 - x_2^2 + 2 x_1 x_3 - x_0 x_4 = 0,$$
$$-x_1^2 + x_0 x_2 - x_1 x_3 - x_3^2 + x_0 x_4 + x_2 x_4 = 0,$$
$$-x_2^2 + 2 x_1 x_3 - x_3^2 - x_0 x_4 + x_2 x_4 = 0.$$

Of course, we don't expect all these intersections to be nice, especially since this isn't a complete intersection -- we're cutting a one-dimensional object out of a four-dimensional space, and using four (i.e., "one too many") equations to do it.

Comment: +1 Did you do these calculations by hand?

Comment: I used Mathematica to take the determinants, but it wouldn't actually be that tough to do by hand.  It's going to work generically, after all, so the first thing you try should work unless you're incredibly unlucky.

Comment: Dear Daniel,  yes, I know that these calculations can be done by hand but I'm curious in general to know how quickly  the younger generation  would reach for computers when faced with explicit calculations.  Anyway, bravo for your answer and thanks for answering my rather indiscreet question :-)